# Node GET by ID API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, axios

I have follow the instructions to create a NODE API [here](https://nordicapis.com/building-a-restful-api-using-node-js-and-mongodb/).
I'm trying to have a few endpoints with a NODE app to serve data to my React UI.
The database is mongodb where I have a collection for 'stores'.

I have 2 GET calls:

1. One to retrieve all stores
2. One to retrieve a store by ID

Node app.js:

```
app.get('/viewstores', (request, response) => {
  storesCollection.find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      return response.status(500).send(error);
    }
    response.send(result);
  });
});

app.get("/viewstores/:id", (request, response) => {
  storesCollection.findOne({ "_id": new ObjectId(request.params.id) }, (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
          return response.status(500).send(error);
      }
      
      response.send(result);
  });
});
```

I make my API calls from axios in React.
If I make a call to the first API to retrieve all stores, there no problem at all, but if I try to make the API call by ID, I still get all stores from the first API.
It seems that I am not able to target the GET by ID api.

React app

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/viewstores', {
       params: { _id: params.storesid}
    })
    .then(({data}) => {
      console.log("DATA ==> ", data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("ERROR API GET ==> ", error))
  }, [])
```

MongoDB store sample:

```
_id: ObjectId("12345")
businessname:"ABC"
businessaddress:"address abc 1"
```

Any idea why when I try to call the GET by ID I always get back the whole collection?

Thanks in advance.
Joe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `params.storesid` is `12345`,
your current React code sends requests to `http://localhost:5000/viewstores?_id=12345`, and the route `/viewstores` is reached. To reach the `/viewstores/:id` route, the URL should be something likes `http://localhost:5000/viewstores/12345` then Express will capture the `12345` part in the URL to `request.params.id`. You can try the code below:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/viewstores/${params.storesid}`)
    .then(({data}) => {
      console.log("DATA ==> ", data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("ERROR API GET ==> ", error))
  }, [])
```

You can read about Express route parameters in the [official document](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).